# Xcode: Module file was created by a newer version of the compiler

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, build, xcode6

I have a project built with Xcode 6.2. I included a new framework that was built with Xcode 6.3 and I am getting the following compile time error:

Module file was created by a newer version of the compiler

I haven't updated to 6.3 because it requires me to update my OS. I tried the following already, much to no avail.

1. Xcode: menu Product => Clean
2. Xcode: menu Product => Clean (while holding Option/Alt)
3. Removed DerivedData folder.

Is this a general issue that frameworks ALWAYS need to be built into projects with the same version of Xcode?

The deployment target version of the framework is 8.0. It contains Swift code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this error is occurring is because there was a Swift version upgrade between Xcode 6.2 and 6.3. Xcode 6.3 introduced Swift 1.2 which apparently is not backward compatible with Swift 1.1. Since a particular Swift version ships with a particular version of Xcode you get the error above.